# does spark reduce can iterate all the values by key like hadoop mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce

in my project, i need consider all the values of one key to decide the output of mapreduce. In hadoop mapreduce this can be easily achieved like the code:

```
reduceFunction (Text key, Iterator <V> valueIter) {
  outputAttri res;
  for (value : valueIter) {
    if (condition_1 (value)) addingInfo_1 (res);
    else if (condition_2 (value)) addingInfo_2 (res);
    ......
  }
  myOutput outputValue = allConditions (res);
  outputKeyValue (key, outputValue);
}
```

could I do the same thing easily by spark RDD reduce function?
thanks

ps: spark reduce (reducebykey) function need the couple of value same type as output, each input value locally; but i need consider each value globally when the other value coming, hence not easy to use reduce function like

```
reduceCall (v v1, v2) -> return (v) myFunction (v1, v2);
```

Can any spark RDD mapreduce treats all the values globally by key?

Comment: example data and expected output please.

Comment: From the Spark documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#working-with-key-value-pairs - specically look for `reduceByKey`.